# How to set length integer in pgadmin4?

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin-4

can i set length on tabel sql pgadmin4?

so i use

```
ALTER TABLE "Products" ALTER "role" TYPE integer(10);
```

But get error like this
https://i.stack.imgur.com/4POvW.png

so can i set length on integer?
https://i.stack.imgur.com/ai2m3.png

Comment:  Please post code, errors, sample data or textual output here as plain-text, not as images that can be hard to read, can’t be copy-pasted to help test code or use in answers, and are barrier to those who depend on screen readers or translation tools. You can edit your question to add the code in the body of your question. For easy formatting use the `{}` button to mark blocks of code, or indent with four spaces for the same effect. The contents of a **screenshot can’t be searched, run as code, or easily copied and edited to create a solution.**

Comment: Why do you want to set a length on integer?

Comment: What is `integer(10)` supposed to do in your mind (it obviously doesn't actually do anything). Are you looking for numbers 0..10 or 1..10 or 10 digits, or what?

Comment: You **cannot** specify a length for an integer column, it is fixed by the [integer type](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-numeric.html#DATATYPE-INT). If you need to have the value below a certain limit use a [check constraint](https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-tutorial/postgresql-check-constraint/).

Comment: @tadman my bad its my first time use stackoverflow, because my instructor wants to add length on integer, but After I searching I could only add length on varchar.

Comment: @RichardHuxton i am looking for 10 digits numbers

Comment: MySQL has length specifiers for things like `INT`, but they're really just a suggestion, they're not enforced like they are on `VARCHAR`. If you need to reliably store *any* 10 digit number, consider `BIGINT` or `NUMERIC(10, 0)`. When picking a type it's worth a quick check with the [reference material](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-numeric.html) as there can be surprises. For example, `integer` can store *some* 10-digit numbers, but only up to 2,147,483,647.

Answer (score 0):

An `integer` is a fixed size data type, and you cannot use a length modifier with it. If you need to constrain the length, use a check constraint:

```
i integer CHECK (i < 10000000000)
```

In this particular case, the constraint is pointless, since an integer is limited to 2<sup>31</sup>-1 anyway.